# Deriving Read Instances for GADTs

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

How can I automatically derive a `Read` instance for this GADTs:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data TypeDec a where
  TypeDecInt    :: TypeDec Int
  TypeDecString :: TypeDec String

deriving instance Show (TypeDec a)

data Bar where
  Bar :: (Show a, Read a) => TypeDec a -> a -> Bar

deriving instance Show Bar
```

The idea is that `Bar` is a serializable type.

I can write a `Read` instance by the following snippet or by Parsec, but considering that I have many similar types to `TypeDec` and `Bar` in different modules this is a boilerplate:

```hs
instance Read Bar where
  readsPrec _ s =
    let (bar, tup) = second breaks . breaks $ s
    in if "Bar" == bar then uncurry parse tup else []
    where
      parse :: String -> String -> [(Bar, String)]
      parse tdec = case tdec of
        "TypeDecInt"    -> parse' TypeDecInt
        "TypeDecString" -> parse' TypeDecString
        _               -> const []

      parse' :: (Show a, Read a) => TypeDec a -> String -> [(Bar, String)]
      parse' tdec s = [(Bar tdec (read s), "")]

      breaks :: String -> (String, String)
      breaks = second (drop 1) . break (== ' ')
```

Comment: This is totally doable using template Haskell. One would just need to use the approach mentioned by @dfeuer (ie. using a `case` instead of `GHC.Read.choose`).

Comment: @Alec do you know any example / tutorial for deriving `Read` instances with template Haskell?

Comment: [This](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_haskell/Instance_deriving_example) looks good.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a generic solution. That said, it's a lot easier to write `Read` instances by defining the `readPrec` method (see `Text.Read` especially, `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec` for some extra functions, and maybe `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` for even more) instead of using `Parsec` or defining `readsPrec`. This isn't the absolute fastest you could write, but it should be reasonably fast.

```
import Text.Read

instance Read Bar where
  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault

  readPrec = parens $ do
    Ident "Bar" <- lexP
    Ident td <- parens lexP
    case td of
      "TypeDecInt" -> Bar TypeDecInt <$> readPrec
      "TypeDecString" -> Bar TypeDecString <$> readPrec
      _ -> empty
```

If `TypeDec` is more complicated, and you have `Read` instances for `TypeDec Int` and `TypeDec String` (using `FlexibleInstances` or an auxiliary class), then you'll likely want something more modular:

```
instance Read Bar where
  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
  readPrec = parens $ do
    Ident "Bar" <- lexP
    (Bar <$> readPrec <*> (readPrec :: ReadPrec Int))
       <|> (Bar <$> readPrec <*> (readPrec :: ReadPrec String))
```

Note that in the second example, GHC can't figure out by itself what types the alternatives should have, but when we fix the type of the second field, inference propagates that to the first field. So in the first alternative, we'll only look for `"TypeDecInt"` and in the second one we'll only look for `"TypeDecString"`.

---

The `dependent-sum` package defines a type that generalizes your `Bar`.

```
data DSum tag f = forall a . !(tag a) :=> f a
```

It also defines a `Read` instance for `DSum` using some extra classes. The general approach looks solid, but I'd recommend two changes. The first is to use `ReadPrec` instead of fussing with lists. The second is to replace the higher-rank `GReadResult` type with the following (much simpler) existential one:

```
data GReadResult t = forall a . GReadResult (t a)
```

Of course, these changes will force you to implement it yourself, but that's okay.

Comment: `dependent-sum` is an interesting lib. But from its [examples](https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-sum/blob/master/examples/FooGADT.hs#L72) it seems that I still have to define `GRead` instances (and write some boilerplate for each constructor of the `tag` type).

Comment: @homam, yes, the `DSum` approach just imposes a certain structure on the instances; it's not going to win you much if anything unless you want to use related tools. I just figured it would be worth mentioning.